# Реализация алгоритма дисперсии Аллана

Tags: c#, математика, алгоритм

Здравствуйте! Стоит задача написать калькулятор этой самой [дисперсии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0). Может быть есть кто сталкивался и поможет найти ошибку в алгоритме. Она есть, т.к. есть аналогичный калькулятор выполненный в labview выдаёт результат отличающийся от получаемого с помощью этого алгоритма.

```
public void Calc() {

    int N = storageMath.Count; // определяем кол-во элементов входного массива
    double sum;
    int myN;
    int i, j, k;
    double[] avr;
    avr = new double[N];

    for (i = 1; i <= N / 2; i++) {
        myN = N / i; // усредняем диапазон
        for (j = 0; j < myN - 1; j++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (k = j * i; k < j * i + i; k++) {
                sum += storageMath[k]; // суммируем элементы
            }
            avr[j] = sum / i; // делим суммы элементов на кол-во
        }
        sum = 0; // обнуляем
        for (j = 0; j < (myN - 1); j++) {
            sum += Math.Pow((avr[j + 1] - avr[j]), 2); // вычисляем разницы средних значений
        }
        result.Add(Math.Sqrt(sum / (2 * (myN - 1))));
    }
}
```

Исправленный вариант

```
    public void Calc() {

    int N = storageMath.Count; // определяем кол-во элементов входного массива
    double sum;
    int myN;
    int i, j, k;
    double[] avr;
    avr = new double[N];

    for (i = 1; i <= N / 2; i++) {
        myN = N / i; // усредняем диапазон
        for (j = 0; j <= myN - 1; j++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (k = j * i; k < j * i + i; k++) {
                sum += storageMath[k]; // суммируем элементы
            }
            avr[j] = sum / i; // делим суммы элементов на кол-во
        }
        sum = 0; // обнуляем
        for (j = 0; j < (myN - 1); j++) {
            sum += Math.Pow((avr[j + 1] - avr[j]), 2); // вычисляем разницы средних значений
        }
        result.Add(Math.Sqrt(sum / (2 * (myN - 1))));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не могу ответить сам на свой вопрос (уважения не хватает), но задачу решил.
Косяк во втором цикле for, вот верный цикл (пропускалась одно значение, из-за чего весь алгоритм начиная с первой точки давал ошибочный результат):
for (j = 0; j <= myN - 1; j++).

Comment: @grandpa: у вас _два_ цикла `for` от `0` до `myN - 1` — оба неправильны?

Comment: Не совсем корректно выразился, извините. Неправильный цикл - второй по счёту из циклов for, расположенный на 12ой строчке. Только в нём не хватает символа, в остальном же код верный, т.к. результат преобразований с помощью кода совпал с "контрольным" из labview.